# Z3 solver outputs CUT 2

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

I am working on a complex mapping problem. To get all Pareto-optimal solutions I used Pareto mod of Z3. Some wired things happened when I deleted some constraints which should be no effect on solutions, but the solutions were one less. When the last one should be found Z3 output "CUT 2" and didn't find the last solution.
So what means of "CUT 2"? Does it have anything to do with solution missing?

Comment: As is, your question is not reproducible and thus should be closed. Please read [*"How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) very carefully, then edit your post accordingly, so as to leave it open.

Comment: I don't think it was caused by my code. Because in other ways, I found the missing solution with the same constraints. And the code is too complex to reproduce without all of it being provided. I just want to know the means of "CUT 2" and is it has something to do with this issue. If the answer is no, I will just go to debug.

Comment: As Patrick mentioned, impossible to answer without seeing any code. If you suspect this might be a bug, please report it in the z3 github repo. (Of course, they'll ask for a way to reproduce!)

Comment: I think you mean CUT 2 is nothing to do with the issue. It's either a bug or caused by my code. SoI will check my code again. Anyway, thank you very much.